# Set Client IP Address of an RDP Session as an environmental variable

Tags: vpn, dns, remote-desktop, environment-variables

My company uses some software that runs on our terminal server and connects back to a peripheral I have locally connected to my client laptop.  The software defines an HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key in my terminal server profile with the URL to connect to my peripheral via HTTP defined using %CLIENTNAME%.

Unfortunately, when I'm connected to VPN with a session IP of say 10.101.20.15, I'm seeing issues where the %CLIENTNAME% variable on the terminal server is being resolved by our corporate DNS as the IP Address I still had when connected to a hard ethernet connection at the office the day before, say 172.28.3.55 for an example.

Even if I do "ipconfig /flushdns" and "ipconfig /registerdns" on my client laptop, the DNS server remains stuck resolving as 172.28.3.55 address I had in the office.

If I modify the URL in the HKCU registry key to point to my VPN session IP of 10.101.20.15 instead of %CLIENTNAME%, the peripheral can be communicated with properly until I close my VPN session.  The next time I connect to VPN, I'm going to get a different IP.  Let's use 10.101.31.21 as an example.

What can I do to get a login script or something set up on the terminal server that will define my current VPN session's IP as a user environmental variable of CLIENTIPADDRESS every time I or another user who needs to use the same type of peripheral logs in to the terminal server?  In my example, the next login to the terminal server should define CLIENTIPADDRESS as 10.101.31.21.

It would be preferable to define the connection URL in the terminal server HKCU registry key to point to the %CLIENTIPADDRESS% variable instead of the %CLIENTNAME% variable or a hard-coded IP Address and not need to modify it every time the VPN IP changes.

Thanks in advance,

David Carter | Technical Support Specialist | Millennium Technology Group | Orlando, FL

Comment: So what you need is to set %CLIENTNAME% to your current IP address when connected to the VPN or set %CLIENTNAME% = %CLIENTIPADDRESS% since the software you are using seem to look at %CLIENTNAME% I'm right?

Comment: What is the client computer operating system?

Comment: When you modify the value in HKCU manually do you do it through the RDP connection or physically on the server?

Comment: Thank you Ricardo for your replies.  Here are the answers to your questions: 

What I need is to create %CLIENTIPADDRESS% with the IP address that %CLIENTNAME% should be resolving to, but isn't.

Client operating system is Windows 10 version 21H2 (build 19044.1415 at time of testing, but may've caught the update to build 19044.1466 by now).

HKCU is modified on the registry of the terminal server when logged in as end user.

Comment: Well I made some tests here using OpenVPN. And even by using a VPN when connecting through RDP the comunication between the 2 computers still seems to be made through the clients computer "real" IP. If you put the real IP in %ClientName% instead of the IP from the VPN does the error still appear?

Comment: If I take "Real IP" to mean my local IP on my home network before I connect to the VPN, I don't believe that works.  The software is running on the terminal server and needs to be able to communicate back to the peripheral on my computer.  The server on my company network will have no way to communicate with my home subnet, the only IP it will see my computer as is the IP my VPN Adapter gets once I've connected.  I've already stated that if I change the connection URL the software uses with the IP from my VPN adapter instead of %clientname%, I can communicate with the peripheral fine.

Comment: While our help desk can assist those less-technically-inclined with the same issue as me in editing the URL to match their current IP, they're going to have to call back the next time they connect to VPN to have the URL reupdated.  I've reached out in hopes of finding a solution that will automate the detection of the VPN IP and setting it as a variable that I can keep referenced in the URL.  In theory, %clientname% should work fine.  The reality is that our DNS issues prevent this from working.

Comment: By "real IP" I don't mean your local IP but your public IP the one you see when you connect to whatismyip.com or ipinfo.io/ip without a VPN. So if you change %ClientName% to this public IP instead of the IP form the VPN does it still work?

Comment: I see where you're going with the question now.  In theory, it would work but it would require configuring port-forwarding on my home router.  The URL to connect to peripheral is http://%clientname%:8555/device/list so I'd have to forward 8555 to always route to my laptop.  Unfortunately, that's not an option for the other users affected by the issue.  I'm given to understand it's possible to pull the client IP that connects to RDP with scripting, that's what I'm hoping to achieve and seeking help with.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, on my tests it saved the "Public IP" on the %clientName% variable but maybe it is different with you since you are using a corporate VPN and I used OpenVPN on my tests. Copy the script to notepad and save it with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension. The script has to run on the server side...

```
@echo off
:: set The RDP port here usually 3389:
set RDPort=3389

for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('netstat -n ^| find /i "%RDPort%" ^| find /i "established"') do set IP=%%a
IF "%IP%"=="" goto :Cancela

for /f "delims=:" %%a in ("%IP%") do set IP=%%a
reg add "HKCU\Environment" /v "CLIENTNAME" /d "%IP%" /t reg_sz /f
exit

:Cancela
exit
```

Set it up in Task Scheduler with options:

- General:
  Run If user is connected or not
- Trigger:
  When user session starts
- Action:
  Path to the batch script
- Settings:
  Run as soon as possible if lost...

Comment: I don't understand, the IP has dots, so string?